# Alternative file extension for XML file?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

i just have a simple question to ask. For XML file, i know that the file extension is .xml but can it be possible to have an file extension of .pro/.m?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only significance of a file extension is that the operating system or web server typically allows you to set up a mapping from file extensions to applications that can process the file (or to MIME types, which amounts to the same thing). And of course it will probably have a default mapping. Given that the mapping is configurable, you can use any file extensions you like.

Answer (score 3):

You can store anything you want in any file of any extension.

If you are returning the file from a website, you will need to ensure that you are setting the correct mimetype for the file extension though (`text/xml` or `application/xml` for raw xml)

You can do this by adding a static mimetype for the extension, or if your using server-side code you can set this in the Http Headers

Answer (score 2):

You can give any file any extension.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Just specify what extension you want.

Of course, depending on the OS, the default action when a user selects that file might change depending on the extension, but there is nothing inherent in XML that requires a file containing XML to be named `.xml`. (For a start a different extension, like `.xsd`, is often used for XML-Schema documents which are also XML.)